# Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-beta1 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop3

I'm using windows native library for hadoop 3.0 beta1 installed in windows 10 environment. HDFS and Yarn started successfully.installed Hive 2.2 with same windows native library with derby db installed.But while running hive server its failing.

Below is the error received while running Hive.
Is there any version compatibility for Hive to hadoop 3.0 beta 1, which will resolve below error.

```
2017-10-22 12:25:53,002 ERROR shims.ShimLoader: Error loading shims
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-beta1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDAFPercentile.<clinit>(UDAFPercentile.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hive.common.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Registry.registerUDAF(Registry.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Registry.registerUDAF(Registry.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.<clinit>(FunctionRegistry.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:384)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:581)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:544)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.applyAuthorizationConfigPolicy(CLIService.java:127)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.init(CLIService.java:112)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService.init(EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService.java:45)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:145)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:209)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1497)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1392)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execCommandWithPrefix(BeeLine.java:1105)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.embeddedConnect(BeeLine.java:909)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.defaultConnect(BeeLine.java:926)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:872)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.cli.HiveCli.runWithArgs(HiveCli.java:35)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.cli.HiveCli.main(HiveCli.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Beeline version 2.2.0 by Apache Hive
2017-10-22 12:25:53,072 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
2017-10-22 12:25:53,121 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
```

Comment: Why particularly do you need beta software?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: As of May 21st, 2018 Hive 3.0.0 was released and supports Hadoop 3.  Refer to the [JIRA Changelog](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12340268&styleName=Text&projectId=12310843) for more details.

---

At the time of this question Hive had not integrated with Hadoop 3 yet.  These are the bugs that were related to your problem.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15016 - Run tests with Hadoop 3.0.0-beta1
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15326 - Hive shims report Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT

And the [downloads page](https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html) showed:

[image]

Which meant integration with Hadoop 3 was still not supported.